# Error -22 when using ConsumerIRService

Tags: java, android

I am writing a program that utilizes the IR blaster in my M8.  I have looked at all the samples I can find, and have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Here are some snippets from my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    int[] pattern = {22, 22};

    ConsumerIrManager irManager = (ConsumerIrManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);

    if (irManager != null)
    {
        if (irManager.hasIrEmitter())
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // transmit the pattern at 38KHz
                    irManager.transmit(38000, pattern);
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                String message = e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR" />
```

**When I run this program, I get the following errors**

```
10-26 18:00:32.703     947-1735/? E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Error transmitting: -18
10-26 18:00:32.713     947-1443/? E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Error transmitting: -22
10-26 18:00:32.843      947-958/? E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Error transmitting: -18
10-26 18:00:32.863     947-1514/? E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Error transmitting: -22
```

At this point I am just trying to get the IR LED to turn on, thus the while true loop which enables me to get a camera and check to see if the IR LED is firing.

I have tried various patterns, and in the snippet above, I have reduced it to a simple pattern for brevity.  I have used cameras that see IR to verify that the IR LED is in fact not firing for this program, while it does work for other programs (such as HTC's TV app).  I have tried running this from Eclipse and from Android Studio.  In my searching it seems that error -22 is an invalid parameter, though I am not sure whether I am giving an invalid parameter, or if the invalid parameter is happening several layers within the transmit function.

Note: While I have the transmit call in a try block, no exception is fired when running this code.